# Can't link with libLLVMSupport.a

Tags: linker, clang, llvm, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile reduced clang "driver.cpp" - added printf for arguments - and i'm getting linking with libLLVMSupport.a error - no StringSaver class found.

```
# lib
echo "compiling cmd builder (x86_64) ..."
clang++ `../llvm_34_local_installed2/bin/llvm-config --cxxflags` -I ../llvm_34/tools/clang/include -I ../llvm_34_build_local2/tools/clang/include  -c ./lib_cmd_builder.cpp -o ./lib_cmd_builder_x86_64.o

echo "linking cmd builder (x86_64) ..."
CMD="clang++ `../llvm_34_local_installed2/bin/llvm-config --ldflags` ./lib_cmd_builder_x86_64.o -o exe_cmd_builder_x86_64 `../llvm_34_local_installed2/bin/llvm-config --libs` -lclangARCMigrate -lclangAST -lclangASTMatchers -lclangAnalysis -lclangApplyReplacements -lclangBasic -lclangCodeGen -lclangDriver -lclangDynamicASTMatchers -lclangEdit -lclangFormat -lclangFrontend -lclangFrontendTool -lclangIndex -lclangLex -lclangParse -lclangQuery -lclangRewriteCore -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangSema -lclangSerialization -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend -lclangTidy -lclangTidyGoogleModule -lclangTidyLLVMModule"

echo "[${CMD}]"
${CMD}
```

Error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "typeinfo for llvm::cl::StringSaver", referenced from:

      typeinfo for (anonymous namespace)::StringSetSaver in lib_cmd_builder_x86_64.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Checking libLLVM is found and contains CommandLine object data:

(found on -L path):

```
find ../llvm_34_local_installed2/lib/ -name "*upport*"

../llvm_34_local_installed2/lib//libLLVMSupport.a
```

(contains CommandLine.cpp object data):

```
ar -t ../llvm_34_local_installed2/lib//libLLVMSupport.a | grep CommandLine

CommandLine.cpp.o
```

The class StringSaver is declared  in CommandLine.cpp:

/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34/include/llvm/Support/CommandLine.h

```
class StringSaver {

  virtual void anchor();

public:

  virtual const char *SaveString(const char *Str) = 0;

  virtual ~StringSaver() {};  // Pacify -Wnon-virtual-dtor.

};
```

StringSaver inheritor is declared and implemented in self file (lib_cmd_builder.cpp):

```
namespace {

  class StringSetSaver : public llvm::cl::StringSaver {

  public:

    StringSetSaver(std::set<std::string> &Storage) : Storage(Storage) {}

    const char *SaveString(const char *Str) LLVM_OVERRIDE {

      return SaveStringInSet(Storage, Str);

    }

  private:

    std::set<std::string> &Storage;

  };

}
```

i've also checked llvm-config output and it seems to be ok (contain -L and -lLLVMSupport):

```
clang++ -L/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_local_installed2/lib   -lcurses -lpthread -lz ./lib_cmd_builder_x86_64.o -o exe_cmd_builder_x86_64 -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMDebugInfo -lLLVMOption -lLLVMLTO -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMipo -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMTableGen -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMSystemZInfo -lLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMR600CodeGen -lLLVMR600Desc -lLLVMR600Info -lLLVMR600AsmPrinter -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMMipsAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMCppBackendCodeGen -lLLVMCppBackendInfo -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMARMAsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMJIT -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMC -lLLVMObject -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport -lclangARCMigrate -lclangAST -lclangASTMatchers -lclangAnalysis -lclangApplyReplacements -lclangBasic -lclangCodeGen -lclangDriver -lclangDynamicASTMatchers -lclangEdit -lclangFormat -lclangFrontend -lclangFrontendTool -lclangIndex -lclangLex -lclangParse -lclangQuery -lclangRewriteCore -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangSema -lclangSerialization -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend -lclangTidy -lclangTidyGoogleModule -lclangTidyLLVMModule
```

Also checked it's build for x86_64 (my host device):

```
lipo -info ../llvm_34_local_installed2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a
input file ../llvm_34_local_installed2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: ../llvm_34_local_installed2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a is architecture: x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use `-fno-rtti` while compiling library sources